# Google API key to access Youtube via PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have a script that pulls videos from Youtube via api. What I was wondering is beings the Youtube api only lets you do 10k quires per day, how would I code in the script to randomly select between, let's say 5 different api? So upon one video request it would use api 01 and then the next video request it would use api 02 etc.

In the script here is where you put your api.

```
/**
* Google API key to access YouTube API v3
*
* @var string
*/
private $google_api_key = 'AIzaSyDLszH3Dlpiu2ANEbL0SNZmiKJoArZLtXw'
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real api key!

Answer (score 3):

If you randomize the choice each time, chances are you will have a good balance between your api keys usage.

```
$apiKeys = array(
                  'AIzaSyDLszH3Dlpiu2ANEbL0SNZmiKJoArZLtXw',
                  'AIxxxxxxxxxx',
                  'AIyyyyyyyyyy',
                  'AIwwwwwwwwww',
                  'AIzzzzzzzzzz');

$rand = rand(0,4);  

private $google_api_key = $apiKeys[$rand];
```